# Write Multiplication Using Sigma?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, decimal-expansion

Let's suppose I have the following two numbers:

$$ a= a_{N/2} a_{N/2-1} \cdots a_1 $$

and

$$ b = b_N b_{N-1} b_{N-2} \cdots b_1 $$

Where a_1 is the first digit of a, a_2 the second digit and so on.

Then how can I write their multiplication using sigmas?

For example something like:
[image]

Comment: You'd want $\prod$ for multiplication, not $\sum$.

Comment: What does $a_{N/2}a_{N/2-1}\cdots a_1$ mean here?  The product of a bunch of $a_i$?  A digit string meant to be understood as a base $B$ number in some system of numeration?

Comment: @J.G. not I meant sigma, I want something like ∑_(i=1)^(N/2)▒∑_(j=1)^(N/2)▒(a_i b_j )

Comment: @kimchilover updated my question

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Multiply both numbers by corresponding powers of 10 to make them integers. Then, any $n$ digit integer can be written as a sum:
$$a=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1} a_i\cdot 10^i$$
To multiply two such sums together, use the distributive property of real numbers.